# Display image thumbnail in modal form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

I want to display an image thumbnail in a modal form based on the specific user ID tied it, and then have the image thumbnail update if the user re-uploads a new picture. How would I go about doing this?

I tried using a query to do it but unfortunately with no luck. The query below brings back all the images in the database as I'm unsure how to attach the unique ID to filter the results.

[image: Screenshot of the result]

The Modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="updatePostModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Update Post</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="themeContent" class="form-control" placeholder = "Enter theme"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="visualIdeaContent" class="form-control" placeholder = "Enter idea"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="captionContent" class="form-control" placeholder = "Insert caption"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="date" id="dateContent" class="form-control" placeholder = "Select date"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="linkContent" class="form-control" placeholder = "Insert URL"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
             <?php
                $imagefetch  = mysqli_query($conn ,'SELECT * FROM content');
                while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($imagefetch)){ ?>
                <input type="file" id="visualContent" class="custom-file" placeholder = "Upload picture"/>
                <img src="<?php echo $row['visualContent']; ?>" width="50" class="img-thumbnail">
          </div>
             <?php }
             ?>
                <input type="hidden" id="uidContent" class="custom-file"/>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button href="" id="savechanges" name="update" class="btn btn-primary">Update Post</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also not sure if this may be useful, but here's the table where all the images along with the other contents are displayed. Each table row has the unique ID attached to it

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Theme</th>
          <th>Visual Idea</th>
          <th>Caption</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Visual</th>
          <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <?php
        $table  = mysqli_query($conn ,'SELECT * FROM content');
        while($row  = mysqli_fetch_array($table)){ ?>
          <tr id="<?php echo $row['uidContent']; ?>"> // Contains unique ID
            <td width="200" data-target="themeContent"><?php echo $row['themeContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="300" data-target="visualIdeaContent"><?php echo $row['visualIdeaContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="600" data-target="captionContent"><?php echo $row['captionContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="100" data-target="dateContent"><?php echo $row['dateContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="200" data-target="visualContent"><img src="<?php echo $row['visualContent']; ?>"width="200"/></td>
            <td style = "display:none" width="100" data-target="linkContent"><?php echo $row['linkContent']; ?></td>
            <td width="170">
              <a class="badge badge-primary p-2" role="button" href="<?php echo $row['linkContent']; ?>" target="_blank">Link</a>
              <a class="badge badge-success p-2" href="#" data-role="update" data-id="<?php echo $row['uidContent'] ;?>">Edit</a>
              <a class="badge badge-danger p-2" role="button" href="action.inc.php?delete=<?php echo $row['uidContent'] ;?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this post? This process cannot be undone.');">Delete</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        <?php }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Looking forward to your suggestions on how to execute this.

Comment: `where id=$id` in the query, we don't know the id field or the source of the id variable

Comment: you have to fetch the image of specific id.

Comment: this is your select part of all the images  & where is the code of linking modal to pop up with specific database id????

Comment: If its the same image name each time, I would suggest adding a timestamp to the image so the code reads a new timestamp each time and loads it again.

Comment: @MohitKumar extra code included provided more clarity

Comment: @tim extra code included provided more clarity

Comment: @Syfer it isn't. Each image being returned is different, I just need to return a specific image (For example, based on the table row id)

Comment: yes i understand that, what i meant was if a user is replacing the image then the file name will be same so make a timestamp for that. Unless you are renaming the image on your side. Timestamp will eliminate caching issue.

Comment: you want on clicking edit button a modal will pop up with specific id with single image ?

Comment: @MohitKumar Yes, that's exactly what I want. The image in question will be the image associated with the table row it is in.